# Could not parse the remainder: '-save' from 'waypoints-save'

Tags: django, geodjango

I am trying a simple app in geodjango by following http://invisibleroads.com/tutorials/geodjango-googlemaps-build.html.
My view function is

```
 # Import django modules
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
# Import system modules
import json
# Import custom modules
from waypoints.models import Waypoint


def save(request):
    'Save waypoints'
    for waypointString in request.POST.get('waypointsPayload', '').splitlines():
        waypointID, waypointX, waypointY = waypointString.split()
        waypoint = Waypoint.objects.get(id=int(waypointID))
        waypoint.geometry.set_x(float(waypointX))
        waypoint.geometry.set_y(float(waypointY))
        waypoint.save()
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(dict(isOk=1)), mimetype='application/json')
```

And urls.py is

```
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url


urlpatterns = patterns('waypoints.views',
    url(r'^$', 'index', name='waypoints-index'),
    url(r'^save$', 'save', name='waypoints-save'),
)
```

It is showing an error http://dpaste.com/3EJVX0G

Template index.html is here http://pastebin.com/125Dm6Bz

Please help me.I am new to django.

Comment: Given that the error is occurring in the template, you should perhaps actually post that template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter to the `{% url %}` tag must always be in quotes if it's a literal string (this has been the case since version 1.5, which is quite a long time).

The one that's causing the error is this:

```
$.post("{% url waypoints-save %}"
```

which should be:

```
$.post("{% url "waypoints-save" %}"
```

but you make the same mistake several times in that template.